# I want to replace PID by linear quadratic regulator to control the speed of induction motor fed by Voltage Source Inverter under V/f scalar control

Tags: control-system, induction-motor, pid-controller, linear-regulator

Can I just use the simplified scheme of constant v/f speed control (the open loop system) to design the linear quadratic regulator? I intend to use the Matlab command `tf2ss` to obtain the state space representation of the open loop system. The image contains useful information.

V/f control:

[image: simplified scheme]
[image: open loop tf]
[image: scalar control]